# A generic way to query for all ERC-721 tokens in a contract's inventory with ethers.js?

Tags: tokens, erc-721, nft, ethers.js

I am trying to determine how to query a single token contract for all of its ERC-721 tokens, similar to the Inventory page of etherscan, for example: https://etherscan.io/token/0x60e4d786628fea6478f785a6d7e704777c86a7c6#inventory

I see that most contracts have a `totalSupply` which indicates the number of tokens, but what I'm looking for as a result is an array of all of the `tokenIds`. I am using `ethers.js`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contract supports `ERC721Enumeration` (check using ERC-165 introspection) you can use that get each token.

Also, if you happen to know the pattern the contract uses (typically 1, 2, ..., n), you can do that. But this is a specialization.

Lastly, another approach is to look for every token transfer and if it is one you haven't seen before, add that to your database.

Here is a main part you can use for this (shown in Node + Ethers):

```
const logs = await provider.getLogs({
    fromBlock: blockToSearch,
    toBlock: blockToSearch,
    address: null,
    topics: [ethers.utils.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)")],
});
```

This is looking for ALL contracts, though you can specialize it to a specific contract(s) using the `address` parameter here.

This is excerpted from https://github.com/fulldecent/contract-scanner which is simple and meant to be studied. That is looking for all NFT *contracts*, but the same approach can be adapted to your use case.

Also, I have narrated and explain every line of code here if you want to dig deeper, see https://youtu.be/lukshxTYpUw and I host a weekly public call [Community Service Hour](https://phor.net/#hour) to answer any questions.